# Kotlin: Apply vs With

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference between with and apply. From what I know the following code does the same thing:

```
swingElement.apply {
    minWidth = ENABLED_COLUMN_WIDTH
    maxWidth = ENABLED_COLUMN_WIDTH
    preferredWidth = ENABLED_COLUMN_WIDTH
}
with(swingElement) {
    minWidth = ENABLED_COLUMN_WIDTH
    maxWidth = ENABLED_COLUMN_WIDTH
    preferredWidth = ENABLED_COLUMN_WIDTH
}
```

Is there any difference and should I use one over the other?
Also, are there some cases where one would work and the other won't?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

There're two differences:

1. `apply` accepts an instance as the receiver while `with` requires an instance to be passed as an argument. In both cases the instance will become `this` within a block.
2. `apply` returns the receiver and `with` returns a result of the last expression within its block.

I'm not sure there can be some strict rules on which function to choose. Usually you use `apply` when you need to do something with an object and return it. And when you need to perform some operations on an object and return some other object you can use either `with` or `run`. I  prefer `run` because it's more readable in my opinion but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Apply plays better with nullable receivers: `foo?.apply { /* maybe do something */ }`

Comment: Good point. `run` is not bad too. As for me, `with` is absolutely useless. I don't use it in my code.

Comment: if you like to scope your utility methods inside a top level Object, then with can be useful to bring them into scope for a small code block.

Comment: What do you mean by **receiver**?  I cannot find its documentation.

Comment: A receiver is an implicit `this` argument for an extension function: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

Answer (score 24):

Here are the Similarities and Differences

#### Similarities

**With** and **Apply** both accept an object as a receiver in whatever manner they are passed.

#### Differences

**With** returns the last line in the lambda as the result of the expression.

**Apply** returns the object that was passed in as the receiver as the result of the lambda expression.

## Examples

#### With

```
private val ORIENTATIONS = with(SparseIntArray()) {
    append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90)
    append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0)
    append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270)
    append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180)
}
ORIENTATIONS[0] // doesn't work 
// Here, using with prevents me from accessing the items in the SparseArray because, 
// the last line actually returns nothing
```

#### Apply

```
private val ORIENTATIONS = SparseIntArray().apply {
    append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90)
    append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0)
    append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270)
    append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180)
}
ORIENTATIONS[0] // Works
// Here, using apply, allows me to access the items in the SparseArray because, 
// the SparseArray is returned as the result of the expression
```

Comment: This really isn't a great example. The last line of `with` returns nothing because you wrote it that way. While it wouldn't be great stylistically, you could put `this` as the last line of `with`. This is like summing up the differences between a knife and fork by saying "well, the fork isn't very good for cutting".

Comment: I think this is a very good example that emphasizes _exactly_ what was discussed. And to be frank, a fork is indeed not very good for cutting. No one has claimed that you can't use it for cutting, but it isn't good at it.

Answer (score 7):

#### The `apply` function

```
//returns receiver T, T exposed as `this`
fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T
```

**Description**

The `apply` function is invoked on a receiver `T`, which will be exposed as `this` in the passed lambda expression. The receiver also becomes the result of `apply` automatically.

### The `with` function

```
//return arbitrary value R, not an extension function, T exposed as `this` 
fun <T, R> with(receiver: T, block: T.() -> R): R
```

**Description**

The `with` function, as opposed to all other scope functions (`let`, `run`, `also`, `apply`), is *not defined as an extension function*. Instead, the function is invoked with a receiver object as its first argument explicitly. Same as `apply`, the receiver is exposed as `this` in the passed lambda. The result of the lambda, i.e. it’s last statement, becomes the result (`R`) of `with`.

Comment: I'm guessing OP wanted to know use-case differences like a contextual example to choose one over another rather than a description

Comment: @Farid - of course they're wanting to know which is more optimal and for which use case not the documentation copy/pasta'd over.

Answer (score 1):

Basically "with" will require one object and that will return only last line. But "apply" do for you like in below example..

```
val myRectangle = Rectangle().apply {
length = 4
breadth = 5
color = 0xFAFAFA}
```

This is useful for configuring properties that aren't present in the object constructor.

```
val obj = with(Turtle()){
    penDown()
    penUp()
    "test"
}
println("test will print "+obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

"with(here class reference required)" is used for accessing variable of another class but not for method of that class.
Now if we want to use variable and method of another class that time we need to use apply(reference.apply{}) Declare a class like below

```
class Employee {
    var name:String = ""
    var age:Int = -1

    fun customMethod() {
        println("I am kotlin developer")
    }
}
```

Now we can access name and age variable of Employee class in onCreate by "with"

```
val emp = Employee()
with(emp) {
    name="Shri Ram"
    age=30
}
    
println(emp.name)
println(emp.age)}
```

but we cannot access the "customMethod" of Employee class by `with` so if we need to use variable along with method, then we need to use "apply":

```
val emp = Employee()
emp.apply {
    name="param"
    age=30 
}.customMethod()
        
println(emp.name)
println(emp.age)}
```

Output of with

```
I/System.out: Shri Ram
I/System.out: 30
```

Output of apply

```
I/System.out: I am kotlin developer 
I/System.out: param
I/System.out: 30
```

Comment: This is incorrect and you can also call the method with too.

Answer (score 0):

### Differences

- Apply: Return the object that passes as an argument
- With: Return the object in the last line of code

```
@Test
fun `apply vs with`() {
    val list: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf<Int>().apply {
        add(1)
        add(2)
        add(3)
    }
    assertEquals(3, list.size)

    val number: Int = with(mutableListOf<Int>()) {
        add(1)
        add(2)
        get(0)
    }
    assertEquals(1, number)
}
```

### When to use `apply` or `with`?

Kotlin documentation explains [the usages here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html), but in my opinion, I find it useful when you don't want to type the object repeatedly.

Without `apply` or `with`

```kotlin
pluginManager.apply("com.example")
pluginManager.apply("com.android.test")
pluginManager.apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
```

With `with` or `apply`. Notice that I don't need to type `pluginManager` three times.

```kotlin
with(pluginManager) {
    apply("com.example")
    apply("com.android.test")
    apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

pluginManager.apply {
    apply("com.example")
    apply("com.android.test")
    apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") 
}
```