# Visual Basic With Equivalent in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, basic

In Visual Basic we can use [With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) Expression like this:

```
 With theCustomer
        .Name = "Coho Vineyard"
        .URL = "http://www.cohovineyard.com/"
        .City = "Redmond"
 End With
```

I'm looking for something like this. Is it possible in Kotlin?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html, https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin provides multiple, so called, scope functions. Some of them make use of a [function literal with receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114818/8073652), which make it possible to write similar code as provided by you in Visual Basic. Both, `with` and `apply` are suitable for this case. It's interesting to note that `with` returns some arbitrary result `R` while `apply` always returns the concrete receiver on which the function has been invoked.

For your example, let's consider both functions:

1. `with`

   Using `with`, we can write the code as follows:

   ```
   val customer = Customer()
   with(customer) {
       name = "Coho Vineyard"
       url = "http://www.cohovineyard.com/"
       city = "Redmond"
   }
   ```

   The last expression of the lambda passed to `with` here is an assignment, which, in Kotlin, returns `Unit`. You could assign the result of the `with` call to some new variable which would then be of type `Unit`. This is not useful and the whole approach is not very idiomatic since we have to separate the declaration from the actual initialization of `customer`.
2. `apply`

   With `apply` on the other hand, we can combine declaration and initialization as it returns its receiver by default:

   ```
   val customer = Customer().apply {
       name = "Coho Vineyard"
       url = "http://www.cohovineyard.com/"
       city = "Redmond"
   }
   ```

As you can see, whenever you want to initialize some object, prefer `apply` (extension function defined on all types). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48736376/8073652)'s another thread on the differences between with and apply.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `with` function from the Kotlin Standard library, e.g.:

```
with(theCustomer) {
    name = "Coho Vineyard"
    url = "http://www.cohovineyard.com/"
    city = "Redmond"
}
```

`with()` returns some result. It makes code cleaner.

Also you can use `apply` extension function:

```
theCustomer.apply { 
    name = "Coho Vineyard"
    url = "http://www.cohovineyard.com/"
    city = "Redmond"
}
```

`apply` - declared on `Any` class, it could be invoked on instances of all types, it makes code more readable. Use when need to utilize an instance of the object (modify properties), express the chain of calls.
It differs from `with()` in that it returns Receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    with(theCustomer) {
        Name = "Coho Vineyard"
        URL = "http://www.cohovineyard.com/"
        City = "Redmond"
    }
```

But `with` requires non-nullable parameter. I suggest using `let` or `apply` instead.

```
    theCustomer?.apply{
        Name = "Coho Vineyard"
        URL = "http://www.cohovineyard.com/"
        City = "Redmond"
    }
```

or

```
    theCustomer?.let{ customer ->
        customer.Name = "Coho Vineyard"
        customer.URL = "http://www.cohovineyard.com/"
        customer.City = "Redmond"
    }
```

Comment: `with` definitely does not _require_ a non-null receiver, its type parameter `T` has no upper bound. Of course, it is true that using it on a nullable reference will (obviously) result in the lambda having a nullable `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Dim  Total As Integer
Dim I As  Integer

For I = 1 To Len(TextBox1.Text)

```
Select Case Mid$(TextBox1.Text, I, 1)
     Case "ء" : Total = Total + 1
            Case "ا" : Total = Total + 1
            Case "أ" : Total = Total + 1
            Case "آ" : Total = Total + 1
            Case "ب" : Total = Total + 2
            Case "ج" : Total = Total + 3
            Case "د" : Total = Total + 4
            Case "ه" : Total = Total + 5
           Case "ة" : Total = Total + 5
End Select
Next
TextBox2.Text = Total
```

Comment: Convert Visual Basic code to kotlin